# CipherLab can't set reader configuration

Tags: android, barcode-scanner

I have a android device CipherLab RS31 with a build in barcode scanner. I'm trying to set some reader parameters programmatically (supported barcodes, user preferences, etc…). But I allways get an exception

```
Attempt to invoke interface method 'int com.cipherlab.barcodebase.IBarcodeReaderServiceInterface.WriteOutputSettings(com.cipherlab.barcode.decoderparams.ReaderOutputConfiguration)' on a null object reference
```

This is my code:

```
public class BarCodeActivity extends Activity {
    private ReaderManager readerManager;
    private IntentFilter filter;

    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        readerManager = ReaderManager.InitInstance(this);
        filter = new IntentFilter();
        filter.addAction(GeneralString.Intent_PASS_TO_APP);
        registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, filter);

        configureReader();
    }

    private void configureReader() {
        Decoders decoders = new Decoders();
        decoders.enableQRcode = Enable_State.TRUE;

        //this is the line where the exception occurs
        readerManager.Set_Decoders_Status(decoders);
    }
}
```

The same exception occurs when calling the following methods `Set_ReaderOutputConfiguration`, `Set_Symbology`, `Set_UserPreferences` of the `ReaderManager` class.

Answer (score 0):

You need to wait for the GeneralString.Intent_READERSERVICE_CONNECTED intent to fire before doing any work on the reader manager:

```
filter = new IntentFilter();
filter.addAction(GeneralString.Intent_PASS_TO_APP);
registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, filter);
```

Then in your BroadcastReceiver implementation:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
     if(intent.getAction().equals(GeneralString.Intent_READERSERVICE_CONNECTED)){
         // do configuration here
     }
}
```